Trying to remove an entire user input from terminal by using the Console.Readkey
I'm currently working on a small side project that allows the user to interact with a calculator. One of the user stories involves using the "C" key to clear the entire input in the terminal, but I haven't been able to get it to work. My IDE isn't showing any errors, but it's not behaving as expected. I could ask ChatGPT for help, but I prefer using StackOverflow since I feel like I learn more from it compared to relying on AI. Note that im still a beginner and im using these side projects to learn from them
this is my written code, i know its all the basics but im trying to get the hang of the syntax :,)
namespace ConsoleApplication1;

class CalculatorApp
{
   public static void calculatorApp()
   {
         Console.WriteLine("Type in a number:");
         int UserInput = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
      
         Console.WriteLine("Type in the operator you wanna use, choose between: +, -, /, or =");
         string operatorInput = Console.ReadLine();

         ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);

         do
         {
             if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
             {
                 int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop - 1;
                 Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
                 Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
                 Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
             }
         } while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
         
   }
}


What is the expected behaviour?

Replace the ' ' in your WriteLine call to 'x'. That'll tell you where you're writing and will likely tell you what you need to do to fix it.

Just use Console.Clear() - it clears entire console and puts cursor position at the beginning.
if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
{
    Console.Clear();
}

Reference:

Console.Clear method

